How we can directly use kerberos ldap service ticket to authenticate with ldap and form the LDAP context
Basic Question:
Can I use service ticket generated for ldap service elsewhere, in my java to authenticate using kerberos to the ldap service and form the LdapContext for further operations?
Goal
I want to implement password less authentication for my Java service running on Unix machine to connect to Active Directory Ldap to perform various CRUD operations on the directory objects.
Note: For various reasons I cannot use keytab file and later on I want to extend this to use the gMSAs to make it purely password less authentication. By password less, I mean to say I want to avoid explicit password management on DC and for Java service running on Unix, it has to be passwordless
My Idea :

Use a Windows Agent Service that can successfully generate a service ticket for ldap
Encode the service ticket (base64) and provide it to the Java Service (securely)
Java can then decode it and use it to authenticate to ldap and form the LdapContext for further usage
The communication between java service and the windows agent service is secure and Java service can periodically ask the windows service to generate the ldap service tickets.
Now with this, I am removing the dependency of password at Java service to begin with
The password information will only be the windows agent service at this moment.
Later on when I integrate gMSA, then even the requirement for password at the windows agent side would be gone, thus achieving my goal!

Firstly, I want to validate whether this can be theoretically possible.
What I have tried till now?
Using Kerberos.NET C# library to generate the ldap service ticket
This C# generates the ldap service ticket:
    private static async Task<string> GenerateLDAPServiceTicketForUser(string userName, string password, string domain, string ldapSPN)
    {
        KerberosClient client = new KerberosClient();
        await client.Authenticate(new KerberosPasswordCredential(userName, password, domain));     
        KrbApReq ticket = await client.GetServiceTicket(ldapSPN);
        if (null != ticket)
        {
            
            ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory = ticket.EncodeApplication();
            byte[] ticketBytes = memory.ToArray();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ticketBytes);
        } else
        {             
            throw new Exception("Ticket is null...Service Ticket could not be generated...");
        }
    }

The input provided to the function is:
 **username**: Administrator
 **domain**: helix.lab
 **ldapSPN**: ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab
 **password**: <my-password>

This successfully generates a base64 encoded service ticket.
Now I am trying to use the same in my java application to connect the helix.lab's ldap service and perform ldap operations. This PoC just demonstrates how we can use already service ticket to connect to AD ldap service (and prove my hypothesis of password less connection at java service side)
Here is my Java Code:
Initialisation
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/etc/krb5.conf");
System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.debug", "true");

Decode Base64 ticket and form the KerberosTicket
String base64Ticket = "<my base 64 encoded ticket>";
byte[] ticketBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Ticket);
byte[] sessionKey = new byte[] {0x00, 0x01, 0x02};

Date authTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date startTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date endTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
Date renewTill = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000);;

KerberosTicket ticket = new KerberosTicket(ticketBytes,
        new KerberosPrincipal("Administrator@HELIX.LAB"),
        new KerberosPrincipal("ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab"),
        sessionKey, 18, null, authTime, startTime, endTime, renewTill, null);

Subject subject = new Subject();
subject.getPrivateCredentials().add(ticket);

Connect to LDAP
Subject.doAs(subject, new PrivilegedAction<Void>() {

    @Override
    public Void run() {
        connectToLdap();
        return null;
    }
});

Implement connecToLdap:
String ldapURL = "ldap://WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.helix.lab:389";
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "GSSAPI");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab@HELIX.LAB");

try {
    LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    // Do ldap operations....
} catch(Exception e) {
}

The setspn -l  command on my DC gives following output (multiple entries for ldap):
ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ/HELIX
ldap/b57bcf7f-d8b5-4e38-a2d2-f6833fe3d617._msdcs.Helix.lab
ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.lab/HELIX
ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ
ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.lab
ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.lab/Helix.lab 

Out of that I am using: ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.lab which I thought made more sense.
When I run the java code: I am getting following error:
Java config name: /etc/krb5.conf
Loading krb5 profile at /etc/krb5.conf
Loaded from Java config
Search Subject for Kerberos V5 INIT cred (<<DEF>>, 
sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential)
Found ticket for Administrator@HELIX.LAB to go to ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.lab@HELIX.LAB expiring on Tue Apr 23 14:01:51 IST 2024
Error occurred: GSSAPI exception:  javax.naming.AuthenticationException: GSSAPI [Root 
exception is javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by 
GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Identifier doesn't match 
expected value (906))]]

What does this line indicate?
Found ticket for Administrator@HELIX.LAB to go to ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.lab@HELIX.LAB expiring on Tue Apr 23 14:01:51 IST 2024
Why did authentication fail? What wrong am I doing or what am I missing to understand?
Any other approach or suggestion might help me but would like to understand what is going wrong here and how can I rectify it?

Update:
This is what the ticket looks like after decoding it on https://lapo.it/asn1js

Update 2 :
Service Ticket retrieved from AP-REQ

Update 3:
Upon adding the valid ticket and its cipher, getting following error: 
Java config name: /etc/krb5.conf
Loading krb5 profile at /etc/krb5.conf
Loaded from Java config
Search Subject for Kerberos V5 INIT cred (<<DEF>>, sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential)
Found ticket for Admininstrator@HELIX.LAB to go to ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab@HELIX.LAB expiring on Wed Apr 24 13:17:10 IST 2024
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Found ticket for Admininstrator@HELIX.LAB to go to ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab@HELIX.LAB expiring on Wed Apr 24 13:17:10 IST 2024
Service ticket not found in the subject
>>> serviceCredsSingle: cross-realm authentication
>>> serviceCredsSingle: obtaining credentials from WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab to HELIX.LAB
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: main loop: [0] tempService=krbtgt/HELIX.LAB@WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: no tgt; searching thru capath
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: inner loop: [1] tempService=krbtgt/Helix.Lab@WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: inner loop: [2] tempService=krbtgt/Lab@WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: inner loop: [3] tempService=krbtgt/LAB@WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: no tgt; cannot get creds
>>> serviceCredsSingle: cross-realm authentication
>>> serviceCredsSingle: obtaining credentials from WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab to HELIX.LAB
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: main loop: [0] tempService=krbtgt/HELIX.LAB@WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: no tgt; searching thru capath
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: inner loop: [1] tempService=krbtgt/Helix.Lab@WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: inner loop: [2] tempService=krbtgt/Lab@WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: inner loop: [3] tempService=krbtgt/LAB@WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: no tgt; cannot get creds
KrbException: Fail to create credential. (63) - No service creds
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCredsSingle(CredentialsUtil.java:458)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:340)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:314)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.acquireServiceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:169)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireServiceCreds(Credentials.java:490)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:697)
    at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:266)


Doesn't Java have direct bindings to SSPI that would allow it to directly use Windows service accounts (and gMSAs)?

I am not aware of it honestly

But the Java Service will be deployed on Unix machine that doesn't have gMSA support and we can't add any extra configurations on the Unix Machine.
Hence I want to generate a interoperable ticket

I see, but in that case another question: How will the Java service authenticate to the C# service? Or will the C# service be giving out tickets to anyone who asks?

No, there is tls in place! The communication is well secured between java service and the C# service

mTLS with a client certificate, or just TLS?

Yes, it has a client certificate as well

Yeah, so if you're storing a private key next to the service, it really seems to me that you pretty much have the same problem as if you had a keytab. If a keytab needs "password management" because there's a risk of the keytab file being stolen, don't you have the same risk with a certificate key file?

Yes I understand, but there are some constraints due to which we cannot use it. To use keytab, the customers will have to do it and provide to us ....and you know somehow we want to avoid it.

With the help of @user1686 I was able to affirm that what I wanted to achieve can indeed be done!
C# code to get the base64 encoded session key and ldap service ticket (Note I have used Kerberos.NET library):
KerberosClient client = new KerberosClient();
string principal = userName + "@" + domain.ToUpper();
KerberosPasswordCredential kpc = new KerberosPasswordCredential(principal, password);
            
await client.Authenticate(kpc);
KerberosClientCacheEntry entry = client.Cache.GetCacheItem<KerberosClientCacheEntry>("krbtgt/EXAMPLE.LAB");

KrbApReq ticket = await client.GetServiceTicket(ldapSPN); // get the service ticket for the ldap SPN
KrbTicket serviceTkt = ticket.Ticket;
            
KerberosClientCacheEntry c2 = client.Cache.GetCacheItem<KerberosClientCacheEntry>(ldapSPN);

ReadOnlyMemory<byte> sessionKeyValue = c2.SessionKey.KeyValue;
byte[] sessionKeyValueBytes = sessionKeyValue.ToArray();
            
Console.WriteLine("LDAP Service Ticket Session Key : " + Convert.ToBase64String(sessionKeyValueBytes));           Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(serviceTkt.EncodeApplication().ToArray()));

Now that we have the session key and the service ticket, this is how I reconstructed it in my Java code:
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/etc/krb5.conf");
System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.debug", "true");


String base64cipher = "<base64-session-key>";
String base64Ticket = "<base64-ticket>";

byte[] ticketBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Ticket);
byte[] sessionKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64cipher);

Date authTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date startTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date endTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
Date renewTill = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000);


KerberosTicket ticket = new KerberosTicket(ticketBytes,
                new KerberosPrincipal("administrator@HELIX.LAB"),
                new KerberosPrincipal("ldap/win-fmclf26tasj.helix.lab@HELIX.LAB"),
                sessionKey, 18, null, authTime, startTime, endTime, renewTill, null);

Subject subject = new Subject();
subject.getPrincipals().add(new KerberosPrincipal("administrator@HELIX.LAB"));
        subject.getPrivateCredentials().add(ticket);
        Subject.doAs(subject, new PrivilegedAction<Void>() {

            @Override
            public Void run() {
                connectToLdap();
                return null;
            }
        });

This is the implementation for connectToLdap()
String ldapURL = "ldap://hostname.example.lab:389";
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "GSSAPI");

LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

I was able to form the LdapContext and perform directory operations using the context as well

Currently this is not possible with gMSAs!


Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)

This seems to be the Java Kerberos error code for ASN.1 decoding errors – i.e. it found a different ASN.1 field than it expected. This looks like a similar issue to https://github.com/dotnet/Kerberos.NET/issues/49, i.e. you might be getting the wrong structure as the "ticket" from the C# code.
I'm not sure exactly what the mismatch is, so first I'd dump the ticket bytes into a file and run it through any ASN.1 DER decoder (e.g. dumpasn1 or openssl asn1parse -i -inform DER or even asn1js) and compare it to what a normal ticket should look like.
$ cat ticket.bin | ./dumpasn1
  0 594: [APPLICATION 1] {
  4 590:   SEQUENCE {
  8   3:     [0] {
 10   1:       INTEGER 5
       :       }
 13  14:     [1] {
 15  12:       GeneralString 'HELIX.LAB'
       :       }
 29  27:     [2] {
 31  25:       SEQUENCE {
 33   3:         [0] {
 35   1:           INTEGER 3
       :           }
 38  18:         [1] {
 40  16:           SEQUENCE {
 42   4:             GeneralString 'ldap'
 48   8:             GeneralString 'WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.lab'

If your ticket looks like this, the problem is on the Java side; if it looks different, the problem is with the way you extract it on the C# side.

This is what the ticket looks like after decoding it on https://lapo.it/asn1js

That's definitely not a ticket. That's the actual authentication token that would be sent to the LDAP server.
(Actually, the KrbApReq type definition in your C# code already kind-of implies that this would be the case, but it goes even further – the message isn't even an AP-REQ, it's a SPNEGO token that has an AP-REQ inside, and the real ticket is some 5 layers of data structures inside.)
Roughly:
GSSAPI SPNEGO token          (starts with the 1.3.6.1.5.5.2 OID)
└ GSSAPI Kerberos token      (starts with the 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2 OID)
  └ Kerberos AP-REQ message  (starts at the [APPLICATION 14] tag)
    ├ Kerberos ticket        (starts at the [APPLICATION 1] tag)
    └ Authenticator

So the problem is definitely on the side of the C# agent. I have no experience with Kerberos.NET, though, so I don't know what the correct function to call is.

Out of that I am using: ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.lab which I thought made more sense.

Yes, ldap/<fqdn> is the standard one outside of AD, but keep in mind that non-AD Kerberos is usually case-sensitive, unlike SSPI – the SPN you're using for the GSSAPI auth needs to exactly match the SPN on the ticket.

Why did authentication fail? What wrong am I doing

At first glance (I'm not familiar with AD specifics), I see only one issue but it's a major one: You're exporting only the ticket but not the session key. Those two are inseparable, as the ticket itself carries a second (encrypted) copy of the key that the server will decrypt.
The ticket alone is not enough for authentication (and Kerberos pretty much treats it as "public" data). Every time you authenticate, the client must generate an one-time "authenticator" using the session key, and must send both the ticket and the authenticator to the server. (The ticket+session key can be reused, but the authenticator is single-use.)
Defining the session key as new byte[] {0x00, 0x01, 0x02} will therefore not work at all. (More so because that's too short for an AES key, as well.)
Related to the session key, you are currently hardcoding enctype 18 (aes256-hmac-sha1), but you're not checking anywhere that your ticket was in fact for enctype 18. This is another parameter you must export together with the ticket. (Although the ticket enctype and the session-key enctype have usually been the same in the past, they are not guaranteed to be.)
(I'm also not sure about your new KerberosPrincipal() calls. One of them is missing the @HELIX.LAB realm; you probably should include that explicitly unless you are 120% sure that Java will append the correct default realm.)

One missing part of your plan is the communications between the C# agent and the Java service. How exactly will tickets get from the agent on Windows system A to the service on Unix system B?
If the Unix service requests them from the agent over the network, then that request needs to be authenticated somehow – and you're back to needing to store some kind of password on the Unix service that lets it get tickets, exactly as if you had just used a static Kerberos keytab in the first place. Even if you're storing a TLS client certificate, that's still literally the same thing as a Kerberos keytab.

Thanks for your response
Yes, I had figured out that session key is required and I got that (but that did not work)
For EType, yes I also figured that out and put the correct value in place
But none worked...

You are right about using certificates, but due to some extra constraints that I cannot write all down, we cannot have cert based authentication for ldap (I know this could solve many problems...but sadly we can't) Hence I am working on this PoC. I just wanted to validate whether I can recreate the tgt or the service ticket at java side and reuse it!!

Well, that wasn't exactly the point – there are really no major security advantages in cert authentication for LDAP versus keytab authentication, both are roughly on the same level – the point was that it doesn't sound like your project is avoiding any of the "password management" problems... Can you try to compile dumpasn1 and run the ticket through it, or upload it to https://lapo.it/asn1js/, and see if the structure looks like what a ticket should?

Yes, going forward we will be coming up with solution for it as well. But as the first step, we want to get rid of passwords between the java service and ldap authentication.
The Java service intends to integrate more than 1 DC
Also, moving forward, instead of a normal user account we would go with the gMSAs.
I decoded using https://lapo.it/asn1js and I can see the ticket being decoded ....not sure about the validity of the data since i don't understand it much...but can see relevant details. If you are open, can we connect elsewhere?

Note: I have added the image of the decoded ticket in my question ....
If needed i can add details from the java side as well, just let me know what else do you need..

I'm looking at the screenshot, and yeah, that's definitely not a ticket. That looks like the actual AP-REQ message made out of a ticket and authenticator – i.e. it's the thing GSSAPI would send to the LDAP server – and although the actual ticket is still somewhere inside, it's deep in the structures (starts at the 'Application 1' some ~15 lines down). Compare with the ticket in my post; the output is differently formatted but you can see the overall structure.

okay, got it. Let me check if I can get the actual ticket.
I am currently using Kerberos.NET library ...are you aware how I can do it and is it possible to achieve what I am doing, I mean is that feasible and correct?
I am a newbie to C#, kerberos etc hence I just want to validate my thoughts..

It should be possible, especially given that Kerberos.NET performs all the protocol exchanges by itself, so it definitely has access to the ticket; it's probably just a matter of finding the correct function/method to call. However, if you plan on using gMSA later, I suspect you'll need to migrate the agent to SSPI for that to work?... (For that matter, I'm sure it should be possible even with SSPI, as the ticket is not sensitive information, only the session key is, and SSPI definitely allows retrieving the session key.)

Ok, can you provide more more information on I can use gMSA?
Can't I use the same Kerberos.NET library to get the ticket for gMSA as well? I can configure to run the service in the gMSA's context...
Update: I am attaching the screenshot for the ticket ...as you pointed, it starts with Application[1] tag

I have practically no idea about gMSAs; the only thing I know is that Windows seems to automatically retrieve the password and set up SSPI credentials for the service context (without actually telling you the password). So I assume that with SSPI it would be the same as using a normal account (you ask SSPI to get a ticket and you get a ticket), whereas with Kerberos.NET it probably wouldn't work as you don't know the password for the account.

The second screenshot seems to be fine – asn1.js is mis-identifying it as part of an X.509 certificate, but the incorrect field names aside, the actual structure looks about right for a Kerberos ticket.

Yes, I have moved forward in Java as well, now getting another error. I will check around it and update the question shortly...

I have updated the question...
I think the java service is going to fetch the krbtgt....I don't know why that is required, since it already has a service ticket!

Note: The java code remains the same, corrected the minor mistake at env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "ldap/WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab@HELIX.LAB"); the principal is Administrator@HELIX.LAB since the service ticket is issued to the Administrator

I was guessing it might be the "case-sensitive" issue – Helix.Lab and helix.lab are only the same to Windows/AD, but different to all other Kerberos implementations – but on closer look it seems the client thinks WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.Lab is its local realm (because it's trying to get a cross-realm TGT for krbtgt/<remote>@<local>, not just any regular TGT). Could it be that that's specified as the default_realm in your /etc/krb5.conf?

[libdefaults]
default_checksum = rsa-md5
default_realm = HELIX.LAB
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
[realms]
HELIX.LAB = {
kdc = WIN-FMCLF26TASJ.Helix.lab
}
[domain_realm]
.helix.lab = HELIX.LAB
helix.lab = HELIX.LAB
This is my krb5.conf

If i remove default_realm from the krb5.conf, java gives an error saying:
Loading krb5 profile at /etc/krb5.conf
Loaded from Java config
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm

If i just add following in my code
KerberosTicket ticket = new KerberosTicket(ticketBytes,
new KerberosPrincipal("Admininstrator@HELIX.LAB"),
new KerberosPrincipal("ldap/HELIX.LAB"),
sessionKey, 18, null, authTime, startTime, endTime, renewTill, null);
Note: I am using ldap/HELIX.LAB
I am getting



CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
KrbException: Invalid AES key length: 1203 bytes




That default_checksum = rsa-md5 looks a bit off (both because it seems to be a very obsolete Java-specific setting and because Kerberos doesn't use RSA), but other than that I've no idea. Though ldap/HELIX.LAB doesn't seem right either...

(Partially related thought: Instead of transporting raw tickets and their various parameters, it would be much easier to transport a MIT ticket cache file and point KRB5CCNAME at it – as I'm pretty sure Kerberos.NET can write one, and Java definitely can read one.)

Okay, I will try that one as well...

Can I load the cache file in memory, I mean can i parse and store the tickets in memory from the cache file since I don't want to use the cache which is not required for another feature that we support
